# How do I link another table into my trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm new to SQL but I'm trying to create a trigger that checks that prices are appropriately changed. However, one of the columns I need comes from another table and I'm not quite sure how to declare that variable. This is my current attempt.

The `ACCESSORY` table is a child of the `PRODUCT` table being connected with `ProductCode` and has only 1 other column called `Class` which stands for classification. The trigger I created is currently for the `PRODUCT` table as that is where all the prices are recorded.

```
CREATE TRIGGER PriceCheck1
ON PRODUCT
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @ProductCode AS Char(6),
            @ProductName AS VarChar(50),
            @StockLevel  AS Int,
            @OldPrice    AS Deciaml(10,2), @NewPrice AS Deciaml(10,2),
            @ProductType AS VarChar(9)
            --@Class       AS VarChar(20)

    SELECT  
        @ProductCode = ProductCode, @ProductName = ProductName,
        @StockLevel = ProductStockLevel, @NewPrice = ProductPrice,
        @ProductType = ProductType --@Class = Class
    FROM    
        inserted;
    --FROM    #TempTable

    SELECT  
        @ProductCode = ProductCode, @ProductName = ProductName,
        @StockLevel = ProductStockLevel, @OldPrice = ProductPrice,
        @ProductType = ProductType
    FROM    
        deleted;

    IF UPDATE(ProductPrice)
    BEGIN
        IF (@ProductType = 'Food Item' AND @NewPrice > 200)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('The price of food item cannot exceed $200.', 16, 1)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
        ELSE IF (@ProductType = 'Accessory' AND @NewPrice < 50)--AND @Class = 'Bed and Bedding'
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('The price of any accessory with a classification that includes the word bed cannot be less than $50.', 16, 1)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
        ELSE
            PRINT 'Price of Product Code ' + @ProductCode + ' has been changed from $' + Cast(@OldPrice AS nVarChar(10)) + ' to $' + Cast(@NewPrice AS nVarChar(10)) + '.'
    END
END
```

The trigger works fine, but now when I tried to bring the `accessory` table in, the trigger doesn't even fire when i update the table. Also is there a way where i can print out the prices with 2 decimal places? Currently, they throw back the error that it is unable to convert it to decimal from NVarChar even when I used cast.

Comment: `"The trigger works fine without the commented out areas..."` I suppose it works only because you `UPDATE` 1 row. Ps `RAISERROR('The price of food item cannot exceed $200.', 16, 1)` Why don't you use a `CHECK` constraint for that?

Comment: Its a requirement to use a trigger for the question i'm doing, I can change it to print also

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: I suppose then it's a home work. If you're going to learn you need to learn with the correct way. A `CHECK` constraint is the best way to do so not a `TRIGGER`. eg: `CONSTRAINT CHK_Whatever CHECK( CASE WHEN ProductType = 'Food' AND Price > 200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END <> 1)`

Comment: Okay, how do i go about fixing my trigger to take that into account. I'm quite new to SQL so i don't know much except the basics. @marc_s

Comment: The check constraint is set when creating tables am i right? @Sami

Comment: You can also ALTER the table to add the constraint.  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_add_constraint.asp

Comment: You were told all about the flaws in your previous question. You are making trivial changes but avoiding the very significant flaws. You MUST learn to write code using set-based logic. And to be frank - a trigger is an inappropriate task for someone "new to sql".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's a **set-based** approach that takes into account that an update of more than 1 row at once will only fire the trigger once:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PriceCheck1
ON PRODUCT
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- check if we have any rows that the "ProductPrice" was updated 
    -- for a "Food Item" and a new price of over $200
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM Inserted i
               INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.PrimaryKeyColumn = d.PrimaryKeyColumn
               WHERE
                   i.ProductPrice <> d.ProductPrice   -- ProductPrice was updated
                   AND i.ProductType = "Food Item"    -- for a "Food Item"
                   AND i.ProductPrice > 200           -- new price over $200
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('The price of food item cannot exceed $200.', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END;

    -- check if we have any rows that the "ProductPrice" was updated 
    -- for a "Accessory" and a new price of under $50
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM Inserted i
               INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.PrimaryKeyColumn = d.PrimaryKeyColumn
               WHERE
                   i.ProductPrice <> d.ProductPrice   -- ProductPrice was updated
                   AND i.ProductType = "Accessory"    -- for a "Food Item"
                   AND i.ProductPrice < 50            -- new price under $50
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('The price of any accessory with a classification that includes the word bed cannot be less than $50.', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END;
END
```

You need to join the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables on the primary key column (which I don't know which it is - you didn't specify that in your question - so please replace `PrimaryKeyColumn` with the actual primary key column's name).

Also, I left out the `PRINT` statement, since in a trigger, you cannot have any UI interaction - that `PRINT` goes into the digital nirvana without being useful to anyone.

Comment: Really appreciate this! In my previous question, I'm still trying to fully understand what the other guy is trying to say but I applied the changes he said to the best of my knowledge. As for the question given to me, my school has a very flawed way to teaching but basically i have only 6 weeks to learn about SQL and triggers are one of the topics. I definitely have alot more to learn and i'm actively trying find more resources.